# py2exe Python 3.4, what dll

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm trying to create an exe from a python script.
I've read the instractions on the py2exe site, and the exe works on my PC, but it another it tells me "MSVCR100.DLL is missing".

Now i'm confused, on the site they tell me to use MSVCP90.DLL but the exe wants MSVCR100.DLL.

another thing, do i include it with the 'dist' folder, or just point setup.py to a location where that DLL is located?

I'm using python 3.4

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Python 3.3, the Windows build of Python is built using Visual Studio 2010. So you will need to use `MSVCR100.DLL` for Python 3.3 or 3.4.

See [this tutorial step](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step52) for specifying the correct library. Just replace the `*90.DLL` by `*100.DLL`.

Note that starting with Python 3.5, Visual Studio 2015 is being used, which introduces a new way of distributing the CRT, so you won’t need a `MSVCR140.dll` but something else instead. It’s likely that py2exe will take a while to become compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the computer you want to run the program on is missing the Microsoft Visual C++ libraries that you can download from Microsoft website:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555 (32bit) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632 (64bit)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include MS VC redistributable with your program as per [py2exe tutorial - Providing the Microsoft Visual C runtime DLL](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5).

Possible ways include:

- distribute the redist installer alongside your program as per [Can Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package be freely redistributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643760/can-microsoft-visual-c-2008-redistributable-package-be-freely-redistributed)
- distribute just the DLLs with your program as per [Is it possible to build exe on Vista and deploy on XP using py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635356/is-it-possible-to-build-exe-on-vista-and-deploy-on-xp-using-py2exe)

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed in PyInstaller 3.2.1 (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/CHANGES.html#id1).  If possible, upgrade to that version.  That resolved the issue in my test.