# Py2Exe Error: Missing run-py3.5-win-amd64.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

Receiving the following when running Py2Exe:

```
running py2exe

12 missing Modules
------------------
? Image                               imported from openpyxl.drawing.image
? PIL._imagingagg                     imported from PIL.ImageDraw
? PyQt5                               imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PySide                              imported from PIL.ImageQt
? _abcoll                             imported from openpyxl.compat.odict
? _imaging_gif                        imported from PIL.GifImagePlugin
? _util                               imported from PIL.ImageCms
? cffi                                imported from PIL.Image, PIL.PyAccess
? lxml                                imported from openpyxl.xml, openpyxl.xml.functions
? openpyxl.tests                      imported from openpyxl.reader.excel
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? tkinter                             imported from PIL.ImageTk
Building 'dist\dlpreport.exe'.
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\py2exe\\run-py3.5-win-amd64.exe'
```

I'm assuming this is because Py2Exe is currently built for Python 3.4 but am wondering if there is a way to force it through (without installing another Python build).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963057/is-there-a-py2exe-version-thats-compatible-with-python-3-5

Answer (score 1):

If those modules are not of any use for your application then just add exclude command in your setup file. It will automatically exclude those modules and stop sending warnings.

```
    setup(
    options={'py2exe':{'excludes':['Image','PIL._imagingagg','PyQt4',
    'PyQt5','_abcoll','_imaging_gif','_util','cffi','lxml','openpyxl.tests',
    'readline','tkinter']}},
     )
```

Comment: Unfortunately a few of those are used in my application.