# Py2exe for Python 3.5.2 not working

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe

```
C:\Users\Other\Desktop\DoA-Tools>python "C:/Users/Other/Desktop/DoA-Tools/convert doa-tools.py" py2exe
running py2exe

  1 missing Modules
  ------------------
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
Building 'dist\DoA-Tools.exe'.
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Other\\Desktop\\Python3.5.2\\lib\\site-packages\\py2exe\\run-py3.5-win32.exe'
```

I downloaded py2exe (`pip install py2exe`), and Im using Python 3.5.2. I have a script that I need to be an executable file, but I keep getting the above error when I try `python <filename> py2exe`. Any ideas? I tried to remove and redownload, but that didn't work

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36508064/1534504) answer mentions that py2exe does not support python 3.5