# Py2exe not working for Python 3.5.1

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe

Is Py2exe just not supported for Python3 or is there something wrong with

```
build_exe my_script.py
```

The imports I made in my_script.py are as follows:

```
import os
import sys
import getpass
import hashlib
import platform
import base64
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
```

But according to the documentation on Py2exe.org they say that they use an automatic module finder so you needn't worry about specific imports or whatever.

Can't figure out why I keep getting these errors

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a py2exe version that's compatible with python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963057/is-there-a-py2exe-version-thats-compatible-with-python-3-5)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as of November 2017 there is no Python 3.5 support for [py2exe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.2).